# Where is this border coming from on my empty div? (even in isolated environment)

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a coloured "blob" with a parallax scroll in the background. This is my current CSS, and the blob (an empty  with class name "blob"), remains fixed as you scroll down the page:

```
.blob1 {
    background: #FFFAD1;
    border-radius:40%;
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
    width:40%;
    top:10%;
    right: -20%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20em;
    overflow: scroll; 
}
```

[image: blob with mystery border]

I have no idea where that little box/border at the end is coming from though. Has anyone seen something like this before?

**Bonus round:** I have got the  scrolling with the page (`position: fixed`), but what I really want is for it to slowly move upwards as I scroll down. How might I achieve something like that?

Code

```css
.blob1 {
  background: #FFFAD1;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform: rotate(-130deg);
  width: 40%;
  top: 40%;
  right: -20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 20em;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="blob1"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see that border. Hmm.

Comment: Those lines are scrollbars, at an angle because the blob is rotated. Is there a reason for making the blob scrollable?

Comment: @pso they are at the top of the yellow blob. You may need to enlarge the image to see them as they are faint gray.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `overflow: scroll;`  to  `overflow: auto;` or `: hidden` or remove it completly. then the border will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get rid of the scrollbars, you need to hide the overflow with `overflow: hidden;`.
2. When you use `position:fixed;` the element stays fixed **without** consuming space.
   So I added 2 other divs. The first is bringing some space between the two, the second is a background that gets over blob1. To do that, you need to play with `z-index`. You need to `position:relative;` the other div and since blob has the default `z-index` you can assign at the background div a `z-index: 1;`.

```css
.blob1 {
  background: #FFFAD1;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform: rotate(-130deg);
  width: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  right: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spacer {
  min-height: 300px;
}

.get-over-blob {
  min-height: 600px;
  background: darkorange;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blob1"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="get-over-blob"></div>
```

I formatted blob1 values for a better representation, be sure to change them back to yours.